# JTextArea.getText(); Stops to read att first space

Tags: java, jtextarea

Does anyone know how to get JTextArea.getText(); to read all the text? It stops in the first space of the line...
Here is the part of my code:

```
  choose.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
          
FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog((Frame)null, "Select File to Open");
dialog.setMode(FileDialog.LOAD);
dialog.setVisible(true);

String file = dialog.getDirectory()+dialog.getFile();
text.setText(file);
System.out.println(file);
      }
  
  });

 
  
  
  
  
         Send.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
          
          try {
            String file = text.getText();
                      
         Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /k start cmd.exe /K \"cd C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CAREL\\Sparkly && Sparkly.exe configurations apply --connection Serial,COM8,192008N2,199 --src "+file);
       

          }
        catch (IOException ex) {
              
          }
      }
  
  });
```

I need it to either remove the spaces or take all the text WITH spaces.
Google did not help me :/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: `getText()` works fine. Write `System.out.println("Textarea content is: "+file);` in your `actionPerformed()` method to see the content you read from the `JTextArea`.

Comment: It's my external program that's the problem then... System.out.println("Textarea content is: "+file); Works.